# How to disable "Relative to margin" option for newly created constraint in Xcode6

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout, xcode6

I want to disable automatic adding `Relative to margin` when creating constraints in `IB` of `Xcode 6`.

It's nice that they turn this option on by default, but I have to support `iOS7`, so it turned out I have to manually disable this option every time after adding new constraint.

I found this setting for disabling it beforehand, but it's always on by default.
[image: Adding Constraint in IB]

Comment: Still haven't find way to set it by default

Comment: Have you found any work around for this, I am also facing this? or turn off manually everywhere in app? :|

Comment: Sometinmes, it's selected, sometimes not... Seems interface builder rolls some dices to determine if the option will be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin will set a default value of **Constrain to margins** to disabled.

> https://github.com/mshibanami/DefaultMarginDisabler
>   [image]

Answer (score 19):

The closest I've ever come to this is hacky at best, so take this for what it is...

Creating AL constraint while *not* holding Option:

[image]

Creating AL constraint while holding option:

[image]

In IB if you hold Option while creating the AL constraint, it toggles whether the constraint binds to a margin or not. That's one convenient way to avoid re-editing the constraint. Further (and this is the hacky part because I can't explain it) I've noticed that in projects where I start holding option and binding AL constraints without the margin, that behavior becomes the default!

Like I said, it's hacky and I can't explain it why the default changes sometimes, but holding Option when you create constraints is the closest I've ever gotten.

Comment: thanks man, I didn't know this and it will simplify my work a lot!

Comment: Ugh....why couldn't have just left the "Editor -> Pin" menu in XCode 7. This is so stupidly awkward.

Comment: Do you know how many hours this is going to save me! This isn't a hack if CTRL+Drag is your preferred way to create constraints anyway. I wish I could give this answer more upvotes

Answer (score 0):

It is by default enabled in storyboards, I have not found how to disable it.
But in Xibs, it is unchecked when you create a constraint.
A solution may be to create a storyboard that instantiates your xibs, but you will loose every possibilities given by the segues.

So You may want to deal with it since there's no option for that (so far... ?).

Comment: Not always! For example, on a UIVIewCell xib, it will automatically be checked. On a UIViewController xib, it won't... WTF IB?