# Xamarin ios designer left & right margins

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard, ios-autolayout

[image]

Im using xamarin designer with autolayout and cannot align the UITabBar to the left & right edges of the root. There is always a small margin how to remove it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are in **Xamarin** using **Visual Studio** I finally discover how to tackle this annoying problem.

Click on the widget or view in the storyboard. In the properties *window->layout* you can see the constraints. Click on the constraint.

Before I was using **-20** for constraints:
[image]

Now I fixed by having a constant of **0** and changing the constraint configuration:
[image]

Just remove the selection on the "*Relative to Margin*" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Set the constant to -20 on the Trailing Margin Space and Leading Space layout elements to the Superview. I have no idea whether this is the preferred way to do this but it worked for me on my Table View.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode has an option not use margins when a constraint is added.

In the iOS designer in Visual Studio, there doesn't seem to be an option when a constraint is being created.

[Xcode & Visual Studio constraint margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7YZ1.png)

A work around is to create the constraint and then edit it after it has been created.

On another note, you might review why you're not using a UITabBarController which would place the Tab Bar correctly for you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to uncheck the Constraint to Margin option when giving constraints for left and right using auto layout

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092963/how-to-disable-relative-to-margin-option-for-newly-created-constraint-in-xcode)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292775/what-does-constrain-to-margins-mean-in-interface-builder-in-xcode-6-0-1)

[Auto Layout guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html)

Comment: All of your advice points to iOS native interface designers, I can't see any xamarin specific information in there, and trying to apply the answers in those links to xamarin in visual studio actually isn't the same.